# Bad state: No element AutoTabsScaffold (auto_route)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-navigation

I am using the `flutter_native_splash` , `injectable` and `auto_route` dependencies. I have 3 pages, overview (home page), about and prevent page. I am using `AutoTabsScaffold` to create a bottomNavbar but I keep getting

> The following StateError was thrown building AutoTabsScaffold:
> Bad state: No element

Here is my code:

**main.dart**

```
void main() async {
  //*INFO:  the plugin needs to use platform channels to call the native code, which is done asynchronously therefore you have to call ensureInitialized() to make sure that you have an instance of the WidgetsBinding.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  configureDependencies();
  //* INFO: flutter_native_splash
  await initialization(null);
  runApp(AppWidget());
}

Future initialization(BuildContext? context) async {
  // you can do stuff here
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  // FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
}
```

**app_widget.dart**

```
class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  AppWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _appRouter = AppRouter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp.router(
      routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(),
      routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
      title: 'Covid',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(visualDensity : VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
      
      
    );
  }
}
```

**router.dart**

```
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute(path: '/', page: HomePage, children: [
      AutoRoute(
          path: 'overview',
          name: 'OverviewRouter',
          page:  OverviewPage,
         
          )
    ]),
    AutoRoute(
      path: 'about',
      name: 'AboutRouter',
      page: AboutPage
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      path: 'prevent',
      name: 'PreventRouter',
      page: PreventPage
    )
  ],
)
class $AppRouter {}
```

**home_page.dart**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AutoTabsScaffold( //TODO(Current) : Fix this! 
      routes: const [OverviewRouter(), AboutRouter(), PreventRouter()],
      appBarBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) => AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        title: const Text('Covid'),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: const AutoBackButton(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) {
        return SalomonBottomBar(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 20,
            vertical: 40,
          ),
          currentIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,
          onTap: tabsRouter.setActiveIndex,
          items: [
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.amberAccent,
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.home,
                size: 30,
              ),
              title: const Text('Posts'),
            ),
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.blue[200],
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.insert_chart,
                size: 30,
              ),
              title: const Text('Users'),
            ),
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.pinkAccent[100],
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.info,
                size: 30,
              ),
              title: const Text('Settings'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Any idea on the possible cause of this error.

**NOTE:** All pages just contain a Container widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad state no element comes when you call an element from an empty list.
This means my issue is in the router.dart, all other routes should be a child of the home router meaning:

**router.dart**

```
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute(path: '/', page: HomePage, children: [
      AutoRoute(path: 'overview', name: 'OverviewRouter', page: OverviewPage),
      AutoRoute(path: 'about', name: 'AboutRouter', page: AboutPage),
      AutoRoute(path: 'prevent', name: 'PreventRouter', page: PreventPage)
    ])
  ],
)
class $AppRouter {}
```